# Kernel module for SSH/SCP drive

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Me and my colleague have a project, to make a driver which will provide access to a remote drive like it was a local drive (using SSH/SCP). The drive should be seen normally as a drive, and operations can be limited to simple file operations (copy, move, remove), without file listing etc. The driver should be a linux kernel module (maybe not entirely..).

We managed to gather some informations and ideas, and maybe someone could verify them, or push us to a good direction?

We thought about splitting it into 2 components:

- a kernel module implementing a virtual drive,
- a user-space daemon responsible for SSH/SCP communication,

because we can't imagine implementing SSH communication in a kernel module (YES it probably is POSSIBLE, but..).

For SSH/SCP communication we think we can use [libssh](http://www.libssh.org).
About implementing virtual drives in kernel module we found a [tutorial](http://lwn.net/Articles/57369/).

Another case is communication between kernel and user-space. We also found an [article](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html) discussing this, with many possibilities like UDP sockets or NETLINK.

With this solution, we could forget about any SSH/SCP related stuff in kernel module - it will be transparent to the kernel.

Is our thinking good? Maybe there are some caveats we didn't forseen? Is this the right way, or maybe there is a better/simpler method (but still related to the linux kernel, because that's the main field of the project ;)) ? Which ideas we should use? Links much appreciated :)

**EDIT**: It's a project we have to do for an university class - so it's not the problem to find an already implemented solution, but to do your own..

Comment: http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Comment: see my edit - it's a project I have to do for university class.

Comment: Then, the CIFS VFS kernel module might a good starting point: https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git;a=tree;f=fs/cifs

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) and especially [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). That's basically what you describe, already implemented.

Comment: but it's a project I have to do - for one of my university class, so.. nothing already done ;)

Comment: then you could read their documentation and learn a lot from FUSE architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Then don't do the encrypting inside the kernel.

A conventional wisdom is that kernel code should be quite small, and this is even more true for students (because kernel code is hard to debug, and bugs inside it crash the entire system.).

Study a bit was FUSE is doing, and mention it in the project.

Then, have your kernel module stay small and communicate (in a simple, efficient, unencrypted way) with a user-space daemon, as you guessed initially.

Perhaps you are not required to do kernel code, but just the user part (you have to find out what the teachers are expecting from you). Then, you just have to re-implement the SSHFS example of FUSE, and you can use the machinery already provided by FUSE.

And don't speak of virtual drives, speak of a user-space filesystem.

Comment: I think that the kernel code may be essential in this project, but we'll discuss it with our teacher ;) thanks!

Comment: I guess the difficulty of the project might have lessened @shiza's interest in programming as he was *Last seen Jun 6 '14 at 13:26* ʘ‿ʘ.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need any kernel module since you can use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) for that.

Comment: see my edit, it's a project I have to do for university class.